# Pandas treats different strings as being duplicated

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I picked up historical crypto rates, and during checking the DataFrame about duplicates saw this case:

```
Duplicates in rates:
              date curr      rate
17763  18.01.2022  BTT  0.002761
17833  19.01.2022  BTT  0.002619
```

DF contains three columns: date as str type (format '01.01.2020'), currency (str type) and rate (float). I used df.duplicated([date, currency]), and finally Pandas treats different dates as being duplicated.

How do I handle with it? Why is it going? How to prevent this problem in future?

Comment: Can you provide the **full command** that you have run? and the initial dataset **before de-deduplication**? By default duplicated won't give you groups of duplicates but only the second and more duplicates.

Comment: your comment helped me understand, that I got wrong output of this method. I changed "keep" for False, and saw that the DF really contains duplicates. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome! Next time I recommend that you read the documentation of the command that gives you unexpected results, it is clearly explained in the documentation ;)